# UI elements in UITableViewController will disappear after adding custom class to view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have static UItableView to hold UI elements. after I add custom class to view the UI disappear from UI all I have an empty table with no UI?can someone please help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Is it a UIViewController or UITableViewController ?

Comment: UITableViewController

Comment: Did you implement any delegate/datasource methods ? If yes, please add them to your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems for a while with UITableViewController and Storyboard. When you drop a UITableViewController into a storyboard, the UITableViewController 'tableView' property is set to the UITableView instance and the delegate and dataSource are set back to the UITableViewController. Adding additional views seems to disrupt the 'tableView' property connection.

My first solution was to set the tableView property in awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad (for some reason you can't set this in the storyboard). Now, I don't ever add additional custom views to table view controllers, but rather use table headers, footers, sections or custom cells to add content to table view controllers.